# RabbitMQ HA Policy - What if you have different master for different queues and all nodes fail?

Tags: rabbitmq, haproxy

I am looking for a bit of best practice advice here really. We have a rabbitmq cluster of 2 nodes (r1 & r2) stitting behind a haproxy instance on each application server. We have many queues with r1 as master and some with r2 as master.

Am I right in saying that if we have a failure of both nodes during a network partition, we will inevitably lose data?

Situation:
r1 is rabbit node 1
r2 is rabbit node 2
q1 is ha queue which is mirrored with a master of r1 and slave of r2
q2 is ha queue which is mirrored with a master of r2 and slave of r1

If we were to loose r2 at 12:00 and then r1 12:01 which node should be started first? Surely if node 1 is started first we will loses the delta of the data on q2 and node 1 will then become the master for q2.

I am thinking along the right lines here?

Cheers,
Leigh

Comment: Why do you want to have different masters for different queues?

Comment: We don't. But I think the way we are loadbalancing has caused this.